# Changing a div background color on specific key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple page however, I have become stuck on on particular element of the page. I would like to make divs light up when a certain key is pressed. for example when the key "f" is pressed the div to the right of the screen lights up in a different color.

Comment: what is your specific problem? Catching the key event? Changing the color?

Comment: Please provide the codes you already tried so far.

Comment: Read about this: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_key_keycode.asp Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To test this code, click on the "lorem ipsum" div then press "F" on your keyboard:

```html
<body onkeypress="checkKey(event)">
  <div id="theDiv" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;background-color: grey;">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi aliquid ipsam minus recusandae a voluptatem accusantium animi eaque error, doloremque, ullam eius culpa quos nisi est, exercitationem aut, repellat iure.
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var theDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
 function checkKey(event){
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
     if (x == 102){
      theDiv.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you this did help, but how would i set it up so different divs have different keys that change their colors.

Comment: @mickeyMan you can add else if(x == [other key]){

Comment: This is a list of the key codes: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html